# c++ function map implementation

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, functional-programming, c++11

I have been playing around with variadic templates in the new c++ standard and came up with a map function (headers + using decs excluded):

```
template<typename T>
T square(T i)
{
        return i * i;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
const tuple<Ts...> map(const T f, const Ts...args)
{
        return make_tuple(f(args)...);
}

int main(int c, char *argv[])
{
        tuple<int, int> t;
        int (*fp) (int) = square;

        t = map(fp, 6, 8);

        cout <<get<0>(t) <<endl;
        cout <<get<1>(t) <<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Which works. As long as all the arguments are the same type for map. If I change the main to use a slightly more general form:

```
 tuple<int, float> t;

 t = map(square, 6, 8.0f);
```

gcc 4.4 reports:

```
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘map(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, float)’
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Are you `abusing namespace std;`? Where does `tuple` come from?

Comment: @KerrekSB: He says he removed the `using decs`, which seems like clear `using` abuse to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can't pass around an unresolved function template as a pointer (or template parameter), you can only pass around instances of it.  What that means is that your template's first argument is being passed as an `int (*)(int)` in this example, and it *cannot* call the `float (*)(float)` instantiation.  I'm not sure of the best way to fix that, but anyway it's not technically what you asked about.

I don't have a compiler to test this on, but I think if you use `std::function` to infer the types that the function you are passing in wants, you might be able to cast the parameters to the function.  Like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Ts...>
tuple<Ts...> map(std::function<T (T)> const &f, Ts... args) {
    return make_tuple(static_cast<Ts>(f(static_cast<T>(args)))...);
}
```

See, I think you need to cast both the parameter (as a `T`) and the return type (as a `Ts`) for the function since it seems some implicit conversion rules are not working inside this template.

If my syntax doesn't work (it probably doesn't, the `...`s are tricky when you don't have a compiler for them), it might be possible that you could rewrite this as a much more verbose function which unpacks each `Ts` before calling the function, and then builds up a tuple as it goes.  I'm not sure if that is really necessary, but my feeling is that compiler support for all of the `...` unpacking is a little spotty right now, so even if you come up with something that should work, I wouldn't be surprised if your compiler couldn't handle it.